# Excel - How to make a dropdown list insert multiple columns based on selection?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

[image]

The green columns represent the data.  I'd like to be able to select 'Bill' in column K, and then populate columns M and N like what is shown in Blue.

- Is this possible in Excel?
- How would I achieve this, please?

I've tried a combination of if and countif, but I don't know how to populate 2 columns from one selection.  The real data has about 20 columns and more owners to choose from.  Each owner could have 5-8 columns of data per each list owner.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support `FILTER`?

Comment: Yes, my version supports FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
L1:  =TRANSPOSE(LET(x,TRANSPOSE($G$1:$I$4),FILTER(x,INDEX(x,0,1)=K1)))
```

[image]

Comment: In case OP cannot use **LET** function, the formula can be rewritten as `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(G1:I4),INDEX(TRANSPOSE(G1:I4),0,1)=K1))`